# PHP (хитрость) чтение самого себя

Tags: php

Скрипт должен отображать сам себя, и при этом нельзя использовать функции чтения файлов. Ребят, есть идеи?

Достаточно будет просто идеи) СПС!

Comment: А зачем?  
Если у Вас скрипт будет содержать код чтения себя, то он этот код и выведет...  
P.s. убрать теги <?php ?> и код выведется без выполнения ;)

Comment: @fremail, это как бы классическое упражнение для разминки мозгов и тест на знание алгоритмов/языка :) И ссылка, которую я привёл, только показывает по одному варианту на язык. Таких вариантов для каждого языка масса, и самостоятельно их попридумывать может быть интересно.

А "трюк" без `<?php ?>` - это во-первых, не PHP (подсунуть любому интерпретатору можно что угодно не на целевом языке, это не считается), и во-вторых, нарушает то же строгое условие, что бейсиковское "решение" `LIST`.

Comment: @eicto, IMHO, это сюда:

>В книге «Этюды для программистов» Чарльза Уэзерелла сформулировано более строгое условие: программа не должна пользоваться трюками, позволяющими получить доступ к своему исходному коду, хранящемуся в памяти загрузчика или интерпретатора.

Кроме того, с самими вызовом `highlight_file()` что будем делать?

Comment: да я понял уже, я думал надо произвольный файл

Comment: Убрать handler для php-файлов в конфигах web-сервера ;)

Answer (score 3):

См. [куайн (quine)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%F3%E0%E9%ED_(%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5))

> компьютерная программа, которая выдаёт на выходе точную копию своего исходного текста.